# while loop factorial non use break

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner who started Python a few days ago.
I'm writing a code to study and to get a Factorial. I want to write a code to terminate the program when a negative number is entered (**without the break statement**), but the code below has not progressed for several hours. I hope you can help me!
This code works, but the condition I want to satisfy is not to use break, but to exit the program if a negative number is entered

**Code >>**

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return n * factorial(n - 1)

while True:
    num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    if num < 0:
        continue
    print(str(num) + "! =", factorial(num))
```

Comment: You should also check for "0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe:

```
num = <any positive number>
while num >= 0:
    ...
```

Comment: got error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 8, in <module>
  File "python", line 5, in factorial
  File "python", line 5, in factorial
  File "python", line 5, in factorial
  [Previous line repeated 992 more times]
  File "python", line 3, in factorial
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Comment: This is an issue on your `factorial` function, probably when n = 0

Comment: Thank you! By the way, can I leave the continue statement still?

Comment: @S.User You have to: otherwise it will compute factorial also for that negative number